# Right Alt is AltGr in KDE. How can I make it behave the same as the left Alt?

Tags: keyboard, kde

My keyboard's right <kbd>Alt</kbd> is considered to be <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in KDE environment. How can I disable it?

I want right <kbd>Alt</kbd> be the same as the left one.

Answer (score 12):

To correct this one should check *Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level* under **Key to choose 3rd level**  in

**System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced**