# Right Alt + Left Arrow not doing the job in Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox, configuration, browser

I expect it to do the same thing as <kbd>L ALT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> which goes back one webpage backwards. But <kbd>R ALT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> does nothing in Mozilla Firefox browser.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.03LTS.

For example:
I have kept `GoogleTranslate.com` tab opened in my FireFox browser for around a week and I have made numerous queries during this era. Now I want to trace back my queries one by one, by pressing <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> but it doesn't work for me, it does no thing.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.  What Mozilla software are you using? Firefox?  Thunderbird?  What do you mean by "result page"?  What behavior are you expecting?  What version and flavour of Ubuntu are you using? Can you edit your question and be more specific?

Comment: have you any extensions enabled - `about:addons`?

Comment: Not phrased perfectly clear, perhaps, but the point of the question is that Firefox does not react the same if the right Alt key is used instead of left Alt. That might be an issue with firefox, which should interpret both key combinations as equivalent, at least in the standard US layout (where Alt right is `Alt_R`, but probably also in systems with AltGr (`ISO_Level3_Shift`). Only editing the xkb file to have the right Alt key issue an `Alt+L` could workaround here (recompiling Firefox would be better :-).

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using?  this shouldn't happen with default US English, but in some kb-layouts the right-Alt acts as a modifier and its normal Alt behavior is suspended in Firefox. See [this](https://superuser.com/q/1703131/1039759) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1310780/925128)